# Let $ f (X) = || X || $ and $ g (X) = || X || ^ 2 $, $ X \in \mathbb{R} ^ n $. Show that $ f $ is uniformly continuous and $ g $ is not.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $ f (X) = || X || $ and $ g (X) = || X || ^ 2 $, $ X \in \mathbb{R} ^ n $.

a) Give an example of points $ X $ and $ Y $ at a distance of one unit, such that

\begin{equation}
| g (Y) - g (X) |> 10 60
\end{equation}

b) Show that $ f $ is uniformly continuous.

c) Show that $ g $ is not uniformly continuous.

Uniform continuity. Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. A function $: S → \mathbb{R}^m$ is uniformly continuous over $S$ if for all tolerance $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a precision $> 0$ such that if $X$ and $Z∈S$ at a distance less than , then $F(X)$ and $F(Y)$ are at a distance less than $$. This is if $||X-Z||< $ then $‖F(X)-F(Z)‖ <\varepsilon$.

I was trying to make a draft, but I don't know if this is valid: $|| f (X) -f (Z) || = ||\: || X || - || Z ||\: || \leq ||\: ||X||\: || - ||\: ||Z||\: ||$.

Comment: Hint: Use the triangle inequality in this way... $\| X\| = \| X -Y + Y\| \leq \| X-Y \| + \| Y \|$. So $\| X\|  - \| Y\| \leq \|X-Y\|$. Do the same with $\|Y \|$.

Comment: For a), specify $n$.

Comment: Do you need to specify a value for $ n $?